# Is it possible to set the padding between Action Bar home button and App Logo?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I want to increase the padding between the home action bar button "<" and the app logo displayed to the left of it. Is there any attribute I can set to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can't add more transparency to the left of your icon?

Comment: This is unfortunately what I had to do.